# Python graph only plotting one point

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, graph

Currently I'm trying to plot the madelung constant with the argument L. The values obtained are correct, but when I attempt to plot the graph, it only shows one point. I'm assuming its either not plotting all the points, or its too far zoomed in.[This is the plot obtained from the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVwMb.png)

```
from math import sqrt
from pylab import plot, show
import numpy 

def madelung(L):

    M = 0.0

    for i in range(-L,L+1):

        for j in range(-L,L+1):         

            for k in range(-L,L+1):

                if not (i==j==k==0):

                    M += ((-1)**(i+j+k+1))/sqrt(i*i +j*j +k*k)

    return M

list = []
L = 0

while int(L) < 30:
    list.append(L)
    L = int(L) + 1

plot(L, madelung(L), color='green', marker='o')
show()
```

Comment: It plots all the points, but `madelung(L)` always returns the same value.`L` takes whatever value you have _after_ `while int(L) < 30:` ends.

Comment: But when I print madelung(L), it prints 30 different values for M. Doesn't that mean when I plot madelung(L) it should plot those points?

Comment: Going on a complete limb here as i cant test: `plot(list, [madelung(x) for x in list], color='green', marker='o')`. Don't use `list` as a variable name as it's a python built-in and can affect behaviour of other code, so try changing that too if my suggestion doesn't work. But it's an untested guess still.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you for the help!

Comment: Glad it worked. Do you understand how/why it works? Also, the `list` point is important, you should change that even if my comment does work.

Comment: I'm assuming that "list" is a built in function into python, and may cause conflict with me calling a variable "list". For the function itself, its taking the argument L and outputting a value for M for each L in the list.

Comment: Pretty much. The fact you call something `list` here is irrelevant, it's just bad practice. What I made was a "list comprehension" for the y axis. You had repeated values. I'll soon (a day or so) be back at a PC and can write proper answers but I think you can continue with what you understand from this.